# pythonic way to convert pptx to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, python-pptx

I am trying to convert `PPTX` file to `PDF` file in core `Python`

Method 1:

```
import comtypes.client

def PPTtoPDF(inputFileName, outputFileName, formatType = 32):
    powerpoint = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    powerpoint.Visible = 1

    if outputFileName[-3:] != 'pdf':
        outputFileName = outputFileName + ".pdf"
    deck = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(inputFileName)
    deck.SaveAs(outputFileName, formatType) # formatType = 32 for ppt to pdf
    deck.Close()
    powerpoint.Quit()
```

This method works on `local`, but very difficult to get it working in a `docker` container or on a `non-windows PROD`

Method 2:

```
import os
from pptx import Presentation
from io import BytesIO

def pptx_to_pdf(input_path, output_path):
    presentation = Presentation(input_path)
    output_stream = BytesIO()
    presentation.save(output_stream)
    output_stream.seek(0)
    with open(output_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_stream.read())
```

This method works in code, but not able to open the converted file

Error:

```
"Failed to load PDF document. Not decoded properly"
```

Is there a pure pythonic way of converting `PPTX` to `PDF` file without using `win32`?

Any suggestions will be useful

Comment: The net result of your second snippet is a copy of the existing file with a different name and extension. Can you elaborate on how you reached a conclusion that this would generate a valid PDF file?

Comment: @esqew I expected writing the stream into a new file would generate the same content in a diff format.

Comment: So in your second code snippet you expect "automagically" because you set the file extension to .pdf, it will create a PDF? Great! Try ".foo" or ".dll" and write that into your WIndows/System32 directory as "shell32.dll".  It should just create a ".dll" correct?

Comment: Creating a "PDF" file requires some form of a composition engine. .DOCX, .PPTX, .TXT etc. are not composed files (just like .HTML is not). They require something that interprets the raw information and uses their own layout engine to make and output, composed file that understands margins, flow, page sizes, fonts, kerning, and much more.